# Making experts more visible before Area 51's beta phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

**Suggestion** — during [Mafia Wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53075/mafia-wars-the-area-51-commitment-phase), allow committed users to vote for up to, say, three other users as experts, who get some reputation bonus (say, 45 reputation divided up between the nominated users).

**Why?**

1. Sometimes, experts come to proposals without any background, and do not then, as Jeff would like, go on to sign up other users.  It's good to be able to see who the committers regard as the most expert users, since the existence of two preeminent being signed up is a good thing to say to attract a third;
2. This reputation can be used to seed the beta phase, which gets the ball rolling that much faster;
3. If there are experts who would otherwise be sitting in a sea of reputation 51 users (is that why it's called area 51?) become visible, then they won't be repeatedly pestered to sign up by each one of their publically known email address, and so will hate the new proposal that bit less;
4. It will encourage at least some users to look through who has been signed up, which may provoke them to think about who might have signed up, and so make a new invitation.

**Why not?**

It will provide a detraction from [the only thing one can do right now](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2295/area51commitmentshare.png),
and so might lessen spreading of the word.

Comment: The main flaw of your system is how do you prove yourself as an expert? Everyone wants a reputation bonus

Comment: Instead of dividing 45 rep, simply give one decent answer on any other site: problem solved!

Comment: @Earlz: you can't - other people call you an expert. @Ivo: so on which SOFUX site would, say, Jamie Oliver have demonstrated his expertise before the Food&Cooking proposal went to beta? More seriously, there are distinguished experts committing to proposals who show no interest in other sites, e.g., Taco Hoekwater on the Latex&Friends proposal.