# Statistically, how many of the users who committed to Area 51 proposals followed up on the promise they made while committing?

Tags: support, area-51, statistics, private-beta

When committing to an Area 51 proposal, you're asked to make the following promise:

> I commit to participate actively in [Proposal X] for at least three
>   months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at
>   least ten questions.

What it means to "participate actively" is obviously subjective, so let's ignore that.

Statistically, how many of the users who committed to Area 51 sites followed up and asked or answered at least ten questions?

I found these statistics in [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76713/321647):

> - [Geographic Information Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems): **38.4%** signed up, **10.4%** fulfilled.
> - [User Interface](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface): **80.7%** signed up but only **13.7%** fulfilled.
> - [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics): **22.9%** signed up, **16.5%** fulfilled.
> - [Graphic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design): **16.5%** signed up, **11%** fulfilled.
> - [IT Security](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security): **15.2%** signed up, **9.8%** fulfilled.

However, these are apparently a selection of sites with somewhat poor statistics, and perhaps not representative. Thus, I'm asking for more comprehensive statistics.

Comment: I guess you can find out yourself. The number of beta badges/The number of people who committed, disclosed in A51.

Comment: @Rubisco Cool. I guess I could compare manually or even write a script to get the percentages. (If I was that good at coding, that is.)

Comment: then get to work! I'll upvote the self-answer.

Comment: @Rubisco Thanks for the encouragement :) Will first have to consider what method to use :) The only one I have any skill at is doing it manually with a spreadsheet. Sounds doable for a single proposal, but still a lot of manual work. Perhaps someone skilled with Data Traveler or something would be more equipped to find the answer quickly.

Comment: I'll see if I can get rene to have some compulsory free time

Comment: @Rubisco Haha. I like the Orwellian sound of "compulsory free time" :D

Comment: @Rubisco Are51 is not in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/genealogy/query/548644), us mortals can't get that data easy.

Comment: @rene I suspected that might be the case. But [this guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76713/321647) seems to have compiled some statistics. How did he do it? Manually?

Comment: @Fiksdal it looks like that data comes from the right side [bar](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) of any lauched proposal.

Comment: @rene I see. It sounds like that would make compiling this data tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The average % fulfilled is 16.1121212121%. **About 16%** in other words.

Long story short, I used a bunch of things:

- AppleScript to get a list of URLs for launched sites, and the content of their Area51 pages.
- Regex to get the numbers with `([0-9.]+)% ful` and also format them into a list: `(^.*)` replaced with `$1,`.
- Python to calculate the average. Using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039992/6083675).

(I could do a similar thing for other things on the page, but it's late. This is a start, at least...)