# My sites are in 'commitment' - what do I do to advance it?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Hi,

I have selected to commit to two Area 51 sites. Is there anything I can do besides wait for the beta to begin?

I would like to be able to engage with the other users and derive value in the sites as they now stand. I do not see much point to referring people to a site where they can sign up and then idle, deriving no value from it.

edit: I saw a picture where robots were throwing a party about dead humans. That makes me sad.

Comment: Pro-tip: don't watch Terminator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During commitment phase, you're supposed to be evangelizing the site proposal, and referring others via the widgets we provide.

(this is also how you build the referral numbers for the proposal that are attached to you in this proposal, aka [Mafia Wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53075/mafia-wars-the-area-51-commitment-phase).)

[image]

At least, **referring others is how you can help get the proposal to reach 100% and move to private beta**, anyway...